# Posting a JSON with a list

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot and trying to write a simple app for storing recipes. Here's the code:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> ingredients;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> directions;
}


@RestController
public class RecipeController {

    private final RecipeService recipeService;

    @Autowired
    public RecipeController(RecipeService recipeService) {
        this.recipeService = recipeService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/recipe/new")
    public Recipe createRecipe(@RequestBody Recipe recipe) {
        return recipeService.createRecipe(recipe);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/recipe/new")
    public List<Recipe> getAllRecipes() {
        return recipeService.getAllRecipes();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/recipe/new/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Recipe> getRecipeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return recipeService.getRecipeById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/recipe/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteRecipe(@PathVariable Long id) {
        recipeService.deleteRecipe(id);
    }

}


@Service
public class RecipeService {

    private final RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RecipeService(RecipeRepository recipeRepository) {
        this.recipeRepository = recipeRepository;
    }

    public Recipe createRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        return recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    }

    public List<Recipe> getAllRecipes() {
        return recipeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Recipe> getRecipeById(Long id) {
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        "Recipe with the given id does not exist."));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(recipe);
    }

    public void deleteRecipe(Long id) {
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        "Recipe with the given id does not exist."));

        recipeRepository.delete(recipe);
    }
    
}


@Repository
public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long> {

}
```

The Postman request I'm trying to send:

```
{
   "name": "Warming Ginger Tea",
   "description": "Ginger tea is a warming drink for cool weather, ...",
   "ingredients": ["1 inch ginger root, minced", "1/2 lemon, juiced", "1/2 teaspoon manuka honey"],
   "directions": ["Place all ingredients in a mug and fill with warm water (not too hot so you keep the beneficial honey compounds in tact)", "Steep for 5-10 minutes", "Drink and enjoy"]
}
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-07T00:18:07.167+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/api/recipe/new"
}
```

IntelliJ response:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
NULL not allowed for column "RECIPES_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredients) values (?, ?) [23502-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1357) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.recipes.recipe.RecipeService.createRecipe(RecipeService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.recipes.recipe.RecipeController.createRecipe(RecipeController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I've been trying to solve it for hours now. I don't really know why the column appears as null. The request works fine if ingredients and directions are ordinary strings.

Comment: can you paste the working postman request content, if 'ingredients and directions are ordinary strings'?

Comment: @LeiYang I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I meant is that if I change "ingredients" and "directions" fields to String, then the code works with a proper Postman request. I didn't mean that the above code works if I change the request to include string instead of a collection. As for what it looks like, well, the value of "ingredients" and "directions" are strings just like in the "name" and "description".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be failing while writing to the join table "recipe_ingredients". Add the @CollectionTable to the join column with @ElementCollection

```
@CollectionTable(name = "recipe_ingredients", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"))
```

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. The same error appears.

Comment: I still think it is something to do with the plural naming of the table - your class is "Recipe" and in the join table it is looking for "recipes_id". Can you explicitly use the @Table annotation for your class and check if there is a change. Use @Table(name="Recipe")

Comment: I just created a project with your code with no changes - not even the @Table annotation that I suggested and did not have any problem with the post request that you have used. See update of screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've checked my database and there was a table named "ingredients". I have no idea why it was there but when I dropped all the tables and started again, the request went through.